# G++ builtin for getting class name from a class object pointer?

Tags: g++, classname, built-in

As the title asks, are they any g++ builtin function (or any method) to know the class name from a class object pointer?
For instance,

```
class Base {
};
class A : public Base {
};
class B : public Base {
};

void some_func(Base *p) {
    printf("the name of class: %s", __some_g++_builtin_get_class_name(p) );
}
```

Similar to __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ in gcc builtin, I hope there would be a builtin function for g++ that help us analyze source code :)

Comment: What do you want some_func to print?

Comment: to print the name of the class of object p.

Comment: And, clearly, what I want to print is not the Base, but A or B where it is inherited.

Comment: In other words, the runtime type of `p`.

Comment: Yes, exactly, runtime type of p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use typeid for this.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <typeinfo>

class Base {
    virtual int foo() { return 0; }
};
class A : public Base {
};
class B : public Base {
};

void some_func(Base *p) {
    printf("the name of class: %s\n", typeid(*p).name() );
}

int main() {
    some_func(new A);
}
```

Unfortunately it will probably not do what you want unless your base class has at least one virtual function (otherwise the type information may not be available).

Unlike `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, the value you are looking for cannot be computed at compile time.

Comment: Thanks! it is exactly what I want. The Base class "almost always" has virtual function!